# Choose newly created record in dynamic choice in Flows? And filter by related records attached to master record

Tags: visual-workflow

This is a two part question my friends!
Background:
I'm creating a wizard for our users to create a new Policy (custom object) record - this is the master object. In this wizard, they have the ability to add a related Aircraft (custom object) record,  by searching for the aircraft in the SFDC.

[image]

If the Aircraft is not in SFDC, they can create a new Aircraft record, then add it to the Policy (master object). After they have created the new Aircraft record, right now the flow takes them back to the "Search for Aircraft screen", they search for the record and then they can add it to the Policy.

[image]

**Question 1:
Is there a way to create a dynamic choice or choice field to choose the Aircraft record they just created without having to search for it?​**

Now that an Aircraft record has been related to the master object Policy. The user needs to create a new Coverage Record. They first have to search for the related Aircraft that is related to the Policy to link the Coverage to this Aircraft.

**Question 2:
Is there a way to pull a listing of the related Aircraft records that are already on the policy and have it as a choice field to add coverages to?**

For example: Aircraft "Seahawk12" has already been added as a related record onto the Policy. They now want to create a Coverage record for Seahawk12, instead of having to search for the aircraft, can there just be a picklist or choice field that shows all the related Aircraft records already attached?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer yes and yes to both.  You can do both.

Details

**Q1)** On your insert action, store the RecordId in a variable.  After the insert action, in the flow, use a conditional check, if the RecordId variable is not null.  If not null, use a lookup and show the details of that record.

**Q2)** Yes, you can make records as picklist options.  You have to use the featuree of dynamic choices.

Here's one example of how to do use them - [dynamic choice](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide/vpm_designer_elements_screen_dynchoice.htm)